# set Rating value to text box

Tags: java, javafx, rating, controlsfx

Here I'm Using [rating feature of ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#rating). Each time rating value 's altered, I need to update the value in TextField as shown in screen shot. Is it possible to use *javafx.concurrent.Task* here? and how can I apply it?
[image]

here's my code:

```
@FXML
private HBox ratinghbox;
@FXML
private TextField yourratingtxt;
private Rating rating;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    rating = new Rating();
    rating.setPartialRating(true);
    ratinghbox.getChildren().add(rating);
    yourratingtxt.setText(String.valueOf(rating.getRating()));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using change listener**

Use the ratingProperty to update the Textfield

```
rating.ratingProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
        textField.setText(newValue.toString()); 
    }
});
```

**Using Binding**

You can also create a `bidirectional binding` between the textfield and rating (Only if you are good with *not editing* the value of the textfield )

```
textfield.setDisable(true)
Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), rating.ratingProperty(),
            new NumberStringConverter());
```

**If you have to edit the textfield, do not use this**

Answer (score 1):

registered the Click event handler with Rating object.

```
public final <T extends Event> void addEventHandler(EventType<T> eventType,
                                                EventHandler<? super T> eventHandler)
```

write one event handler that will call when you click on rating control.
and then change the value in event handler.